# Unity shows nothing after login

Tags: unity, gnome

After logging in, unity show only the wallpaper and the cursor. I've tried gnome and shows only a blank screen after logging. Something similar happens with flashback. So no window manager is working.

Things I've tried so far:

1. reinstall unity, gdm, ubuntu-desktop, gnome
2. change ownership of `.Xauthority` file, remove it, and remove `~/.conf`
3. reinstall Intel driver graphics
4. this post solution [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) (unity plugin on)
5. `mv ~/.config/dconf/user ~/.config/dconf/user.old`
6. reset using:

   ```
   dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   unity --reset-icons &disown`
   ```
7. set `DISPLAY` and reset

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
   setsid unity
   ```
8. `update` and `upgrade all`
9. update Ubuntu distro to most recent

In recovery mode I get the warning, "running in low graphics mode" but the solutions it offers do nothing.

I think this resume all solutions I could find. Looking for new ones.

**Update**:  will reinstall Ubuntu from scratch since nothing seems to be working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: It is similar but the cause is other. Because this solution does not work